# AOP + Jenkins + Maven Integration

Tags: java, android, maven, jenkins, aop

I am using aop and can publish the apk with the help of eclipse aop plugin. As you already know in aop, a lot of codes must be added into some pre-stated classes in compiling time.

But I dont know what to do if I want to automatize this operation via jenkins + maven. To be clear, I want to transfer the whole compiling (packaging) issues on to jenkins + maven platform. Maven should build the application but how?

Answer (score 0):

Use aspectj maven plugin. Ensure that your compiler plugin excludes your aspects and the aspectj compiler plugin only compiles the aspects. Something like these:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>*.aj</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>


<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel>
        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
        <sources>
            <source>
                <basedir>src/main/java</basedir>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.aj</include>
                </includes>
            </source>
        </sources>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```